# HTML5 Canvas Call same function Twice?

Tags: javascript, html, function, canvas

I'm getting very confused here, though i'm very new to the HTML 5 canvas.

Basically I have this function:

```
function drawcircle(x,y)
{
    context.save();
    context.strokeStyle = '#00ff00';
    context.fillStyle = '#000000';
    context.lineWidth=10;
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x,y,50,0,Math.PI * 2,false)
    context.stroke();
    context.fill();
    context.endPath();
    context.restore();
}
```

I then try to call it twice like so:

```
    // call the initialise and draw functions
initialise();
drawcircle(100, 100);
drawcircle(100, 200);
```

However it will only ever draw the first circle seemingly, whatever order the first circle will be drawn but not the second, how would I go about remedying this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `closePath()`, not `endPath()`, your function will error before `.restore()` so it's never called and the second call will happen with state left from previous call.

```
function drawcircle(x,y)
{
    context.save();
    context.strokeStyle = '#00ff00';
    context.fillStyle = '#000000';
    context.lineWidth=10;
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x,y,50,0,Math.PI * 2,false)
    context.stroke();
    context.fill();
    context.closePath(); //Changed
    context.restore();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kwHT5/

You should always check the javascript console for errors.

Comment: Bah I'm such a fool, Thanks for the help!